# Word VBA: How to change another cell in a table with a content control element?

Tags: vba, ms-word

In Word, how can a drop down content control element in a table change the background color and text of another cell in that table?

My table looks like this:

```
+------------------+
| {{ changeHere }} |
+------------------+
| dropDown         |
+------------------+
```

If I want to change the cell in which the drop down itself is located, I can do it with this code:

```vb
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)

With ContentControl.Range
    If ContentControl.Title = "Color" Then
    
        Select Case .Text
            Case "Yellow"
                .Cells(1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorYellow
            Case "Red"
                .Cells(1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorRed
        End Select

    End If
End With
End Sub
```

I tried to access another cell by changing the number in `.Cells(index)`, but I just received an error message because a cell with another index can't be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access the underlying [`Tables`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.tables) property first, then select the correct cell from the [`Cells`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.cells) collection by specifying its `X,Y` coordinates (indices starting at 1):

```vb
With ContentControl.Range
'                   X  Y
    .Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
    .Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = ""
End With
```